# Move first column in file to the last column

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to move the first column of a file to be the last column in the file. This is what i have

```
awk -F ',' '{first = $1; $1=""; OFS = FS; print $0, first}' file.txt
```

This works if the file has only one row. If the file has multiple rows, it doesn't do nothing. The file is with carriage return and line feed (CRLF).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ printf 'foo,bar,etc\r\n' |
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n"; FS=OFS=","} {$(NF+1)=$1; sub("[^"FS"]*"FS,"")} 1'
bar,etc,foo
```

or with any awk:

```
$ printf 'foo,bar,etc\r\n' |
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\r\n"; FS=OFS=","} {sub(/\r$/,""); $(NF+1)=$1; sub("[^"FS"]*"FS,"")} 1'
bar,etc,foo
```

Comment: Thank you Ed, this worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the spurious CR character before filtering and add it again later:

```
<file.txt tr -d \\015 | awk -F ',' '{for (field=2; field <=NF; field++) { printf "%s", $field FS } print $1}' | sed 's/$/\o015/' > file-new.txt
```

For example:

```
# cat | sed 's/$/\o015/' > test.txt
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
A,B,C,D
0
```

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>

```
# <test.txt tr -d \\015 | awk -F ',' '{for (field=2; field <=NF; field++) { printf "%s", $field FS } print $1}' | sed 's/$/\o015/'
2,3,4,5,6,7,1
b,c,d,e,f,g,h,a
B,C,D,A
0
```

Comment: Maybe not all CRs are spurious. Also, always do `printf "%s", $field` instead of `printf $field` as the latter will fail when `$field` contains printf formatting characters.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. I  was going to do something like `$0[field]` but wasn't sure that could be done - then `$field` seemed to work. Modified it to `"%s"` now.

Answer (score 1):

IF we can/want see the input file as a **csv table**, you could run something along the lines of

```
csvcut -c '2:,1' input
```

This tool (csvkit) see the input as an homogeneous table: example input

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
3,4
6,7,8,9,0
```

output:

```
b,c,d,e,a
2,3,4,5,1
4,,,,3              //implicitly added some empty fields
7,8,9,0,6
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>GNU sed</kbd> in extended regex mode `-E`:

```
$ sed -Ee 's/^([^,]*),(.*)(.)$/\2,\1\3/' file | cat -A
2,3,4,1^M$
7,8,9,6^M$
b,c,d,a^M$
```

With <kbd>AWK</kbd>:

```
$ awk -F ',' '
  BEGIN { OFS = FS }
  NF > 1 {
    first = $1
    cr = substr($NF, length($NF))
    sub(/.$/, "", $NF)
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++)
      $(i) = $(i+1)
    $(NF) = first cr
  }
  1
' file
```

With <kbd>perl</kbd>:

```
$ perl -F, -pale '
    BEGIN { $" = ","; }         # set OFS to comma
    next unless /,/;            # skip non interesting lines 
    chop $F[-1];                # remove last char, the carriage return
    splice @F, @F, 1, shift @F; # move 1st element to the end
    s/.*/@F\r/;
' file
```